# IntelliJ logs to file with wrong encoding

Tags: logging, intellij-idea, logfile

I use the IntelliJ **Save console output to file** feature. (`Run configuration -> Log tab`)

But it looks like the encoding is wrong: In the console, I can see non-ascii-characters like `"äöü"`, whereas in the output file, they get replaces by question marks or something else. So logging itself seems to be okay but the writing to the log file misses the encoding somehow.

Comment: which encoding would you like to use ? in which encoding is intellij configured, and in which encoding did you open the file ?

Comment: See http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your intellij encoding first:
[image: IntelliJ encoding]

Secondly, which encoding did you use to open the file ?
If you use an advanced text editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.5.1.html), then you can select it from the menu:

[image: Notepad++]